# StencilJS | Use CSS "+ Selector " in component

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I am working on a web component library with StencilJS, and I have a problem using the CSS + Selector. I have a Breadcrumb web component, which will contain multiple breadcrumb items (web component as well). Every Breadcrumb item after the first item should add `>` smybol with `::before`. Therefore I use the [CSS + selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

df-breadcrumb.tsx

```
export class DFBreadcrumb {

  render() {
    return <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <slot></slot>
    </ol>
      ;
  }
}
```

df-breadcrumb-item.tsx

```
export class DFBreadcrumbItem {
  /**
   * Link
   */
  @Prop() link: string;


  render() {
    return this.link ? <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={this.link}><slot></slot></a></li> :
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><slot></slot></li>
      ;
  }
}
```

test.html

```
<df-breadcrumb>
  <df-breadcrumb-item link="#">Start</df-breadcrumb-item>
  <df-breadcrumb-item link="#">Library</df-breadcrumb-item>
  <df-breadcrumb-item>Item</df-breadcrumb-item>
</df-breadcrumb>
```

my css rule

```
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item:before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: .5rem;
    color: #6c757d;
    content: ">";
}
```

expected output: `Start > Library > Item`

current output: `Start Library Item`

I think this is not working cause Stencil ecapsulates my li tags and their direct parent is not the ol. I read something about using the :host() pseudo class, but could not got it working. Also I have set `shadow: false`in my components.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the problem is the `df-breadcrumb-item` element.

A simple alternative would be to apply your CSS to the `df-breadcrumb-item` elements:

```css
df-breadcrumb-item + df-breadcrumb-item:before {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #6c757d;
    content: ">";
}
```

Alternatively you could add the arrow to the `.breadcrumb-item` element inside the `df-breadcrumb-item` component, either depending on a property or by manually checking if the `@Element()` is the last node.